# Formula in apex:outputtext

Tags: apex, visualforce, formula, custom-link

I'm trying to display text according to parameter in link.
This is my sample code which is not working:

```
<apex:page>
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(CONTAINS({!$CurrentPage.parameters.apn}, "Monday"),"It is Monday Page", "It is not Monday Page")}"/>
</apex:page>
```

I'm getting those errors:

> Error: Test line 2, column 72: Element type "apex:outputText" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"
>
> Error: Element type "apex:outputText" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the statement like below

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(CONTAINS($CurrentPage.parameters.apn, 'Monday'),'It is Monday Page', 'It is not Monday Page')}"/>
```

No need for again giving expression tag for **$CurrentPage.parameters.apn**